# Should insurer ignore exclusions when extrinsic evidence contradicts allegations?

Tags: california, insurance

Commercial general liability insurance has exclusions that insurer doesn't have duty to defend or indemnify the insured in case claim arises of criminal activities, misappropriation of intellectual property or willful and malicious actions and so.

But, what if there is extrinsic evidence that contradicts claimant's allegations stated in complaint? Would insurer have to honor such extrinsic evidence if case otherwise would be eligible for cover?

Comment: A lot of times what might happen, depending on the policy, is that the insurance will cover the cost up until you are found guilty of something that violates the policy. After that they will sue you to recover anything that they spent defending you. You could also be required to pay for the case yourself, and after the case is over and you are found not guilty of the charges, recover the cost from the insurance. A lot of this process depends specifically on the policy in question.

Comment: @RonBeyer So what you are saying is that Duty to Defend is reversible and the only difference is basically who pays up front for legal defense costs - insured or insurer? But what if claimant voluntarily dismisses the case in the middle without establishing enough facts for insurer to grant or deny Duty to Defend? In such scenario, would it be smarter for insured to get insurer to pay up front?

Comment: "*In such scenario, would it be smarter for insured to get insurer to pay up front?*" No (or why would that be the case?). The insurer is better off by not making any disbursements unless the duty to respond/indemnify on behalf of the insured is certain, quantifiable, and imminent. The possibility of dismissal by the claimant implies that that duty is neither certain, nor quantifiable, nor imminent. Also, what do you mean by "honoring" extrinsic evidence?

Comment: @IñakiViggers I understand that insurer is better off by not making disbursements, because that is how insurance companies make money. However, courts, at least in California, have ruled that duty to defend is much broader than to indemnify. What I meant with "honoring" extrinsic evidence is that California is not Eight Corner Rule state (contrary to Texas or D.C.) and insurer must look outside complaint and policy.